# how to change the shpping cart icon in magento 2 and make to change color on mousehover

Tags: magento2

I wanted to change the shopping cart icon in magento 2 and make to change color on mouse hover. I found the block name  I dont find how to change the image icon in the block.

thanks in advance

Comment: you want to change minicart icon on the top ?

Comment: yes! exactly I wanted to replace it with an image that I want and change image on mouse hover

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your extended file either _minicart.less or _extend.less

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Checkout/web/css/source/module/_minicart.less
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_extend.less
```

add  below css class and alter you style as per requirements here default css is written and  cart icon is coming via **Luma Icons with content value "\e611"**

you can change them to font-awesome icons or your custom image using background image

```
.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart::before,
.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart.active::before {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 28px;
    color: #8f8f8f;
    content: '\e611';
    font-family: 'luma-icons';
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: normal;
    overflow: hidden;
    speak: none;
    text-align: center;
}
.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart:hover::before{
    color:#333;
}
```

I hope this will work for you. If you are using font awsome icons on your site then that will better option and color changing will be flawless

Thanks

Comment: this shows after I click the icon.. i wnated show it default

Comment: could you pass the url of site

Comment: @learner my edit will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create “Magento_Checkout” folder in mentioned path

> app/design/frontend///Magento_Checkout.

and add the minicart.phtml file in mentioned path

> app/design/frontend///Magento_Checkout/templates/cart

from

> “vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart”

with your changes.

Answer (score 0):

::First let me clear that you can't edit magento core themes directly from /app/design/magento!!!::

::If you want to change it your self then, you've to create your own one and make changes as required!!::

::Now let's go to the point!::

::first => Create custom.css file at /app/design/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/web/css/::

::second => create default.xml file at /app/design/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/::

::Now put the file contents like below::

::CSS::

::

.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart:before{

content:url('../images/minicart.jpg')!important;

zoom:1.5%;}
::

::XML::

//make sure to copy the default structure for xml file.

//I have not pasted that here because i am a noob to stackexchange!!

:::Last Step :::

move your new minicart image to the /app/design/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/web/images/minicart.img extension

::Finally run below commands::

::Make sure to remove /pub/static/frontend::

::bin/magento setup:upgrade::

::bin/magento setup:di:compile::

::bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f::

::bin/magento indexer:reindex::

::bin/magento cache:flush::

::chmod -R 777 ../magento root directory name::

::Thank You::